# Regex to extract all URLs from a page

Tags: python, regex

This question has been asked a few times on SO but I couldn't get any of the answers to work correctly. I need to extract all the URLs in page both in href links and the plain text. I don't need to individual groups of the regex. I need a list of strings i.e. URLs in the page. Could someone point me to a good working example?

I'd like to do this using Regexs and not BeautifulSoup, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and thus cannot be parsed by regular expressions.

It's possible to make *reasonable guesses* using regular expressions, and/or to recognize a restricted subset of URIs, but that way lies madness (lengthy debugging processes, inaccurate results).

That said, if you're willing to go that path, see [John Gruber's regex for the purpose](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls):

```
def extract_urls(your_text):
  url_re = re.compile(r'\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))')
  for match in url_re.finditer(your_text):
    yield match.group(0)
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>>> for uri in extract_urls('http://foo.bar/baz irc://freenode.org/bash'):
...   print uri
http://foo.bar/
irc://freenode.org
```

Comment: +1, but just a note because i think in this case the OP is not __parsing html__ he is just __searching__ in a text for urls-like and this text happen to be html .

Comment: @singularity - indeed; that's why I bothered to give an actual answer following the general warning against misuse. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use the DOM object in PHP to parse an HTML document. I'm not familiar with python but this might help: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html